Rounding/truncating decimal places from floats with NumberFormatter (Ubuntu 22.04)
i need 2 digits after the comma consistently but there are certain floats that just wont be formatted correctly? (as seen below) are the tricks around this?
code:
import Foundation
let floatNumber: Float = 17889.055
let roundedNumber: Float = (floatNumber * 100).rounded() / 100
let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.groupingSeparator = "."
formatter.decimalSeparator = ","

print(formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatNumber)) ?? String(format: "%.2f", floatNumber)) 
print(formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: roundedNumber)) ?? String(format: "%.2f", roundedNumber)) 

output:
swift test.swift 
17.889,055
17.889,061

expected:
swift test.swift 
17.889,06
17.889,06

Update:
this appears to be a linux (ubuntu 22.04) issue; works on macos 14.7; haven't found a solution for it though;
Output on macOS:
17.889,05
17.889,06


I cannot reproduce on macOS 15.0.

i’m on a ubuntu fork, gonna try in Sonoma 14.7. do you get the expected result?

I'd suggest posting this on the Swift forums, as that's monitored by the Swift team (unlike Stackoverflow), so assuming this is a bug in Swift on Linux, the team will much more likely notice it there

If you need fraction precision don’t use floating point. Swift has an specific type called Decimal exactly for this purpose

BTW no need to convert your float to NSNumber you can simply use Formatters string(for: Any) method instead of NumberFormatter string(from: NSNumber) formatter.string(for: floatNumber)

I managed to reproduce this using an online playground that was running on linux.
The solution is to not use the numberStyle property and instead define the format manually using the format property. See the format property documentation and the first link on that page for more information on the format syntax
let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
formatter.format = "#,##0.00"


The console output on the playground page says "Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" so I really have no idea what flavour of linux it is and if the solution will work on ubuntu 22.04

this unfortunately leads to missing digits after the comma for me. for some values just 1 digit gets printed.

@lain  Simple mistake by me it should be 00 at the end. Fixed
